# python regular expression, extracting set of numbers from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

How can i get the number `24` and `200` from the string `"Size:24 Resp_code:200"`

by using re in python?, i have tried with \d+ but then i only get 24
in addition i have also tried this out:

```
import re

string2 = "  Size:24 Resp_code:200"

regx = "(\d+) Resp_code:(\d+)"

print re.search(regx, string2).group(0)
print re.search(regx, string2).group(1)
```

here the out put is:

```
24 Resp_code:200 
24
```

any advice on how to solve this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: BTW, if you are going to be using a regex on a lot of lines it's a good idea to compile it.

Comment: BTW, if you are going to be using a regex on a lot of lines it's a good idea to compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print re.search(regx, string2).group(1) // 24
print re.search(regx, string2).group(2) // 200
```

`group(0)` prints whole string matched by your regex. Where `group(1)` is first match and `group(2)` is second match.

Answer (score 4):

The group 0 contains the whole matched string. Extract group 1, group 2 instead.

```
>>> string2 = "  Size:24 Resp_code:200"
>>> regx = r"(\d+) Resp_code:(\d+)"
>>> match = re.search(regx, string2)
>>> match.group(1), match.group(2)
('24', '200')
>>> match.groups()  # to get all groups from 1 to however many groups
('24', '200')
```

or using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', string2)
['24', '200']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

> If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned)

You are doing it right but groups don't start at 0, but 1, `group(0)` will print the whole match:

```
>>> re.search(regx, string2).group(1,2)
('24', '200')
```